In there some description of all the command processor macros in Windows?
I'm looking for a list of the macro strings known to Window 10 command processor, e.g. %ProgramFiles%, %ProgramFiles(x86)%, etc.

Those are environment variables.
In Command Prompt (cmd.exe) you just type in set and hit enter.
In Powershell you can use
get-item env:
or
ls env:
